# Can someone explain how the output of this control system is derived?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

[image]

I understand equation (1), but I really don't see the connection between equation (2) and the picture.

For starters, shouldn't the $b_0$ constant be multiplied by

$$net(n)-(a_1 \cdot net(n - 1) + a_2 \cdot net(n-2))$$

Edit: Honestly even an "I'm not sure" would be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well as a fresh start: net(n) is the value before the node, this can be seen by equation (1). The value after the node is the following (lets call this $x$ for simplicity):
$$x(n) = net(n) - a_1x(n-1) - a_2x(n-2)$$
Therefore:
$$\tilde{y}(n) = b_0x(n)+b_1x(n-1)+b_2x(n-2)$$
Now substituting the first equation into the second one yields the following:
$$\tilde{y}(n) = b_0net(n) - b_0a_1x(n-1) - b_0a_2x(n-2)+b_1net(n-1) - b_1a_1x(n-2) - b_1a_2x(n-3)+b_2net(n-2) - b_2a_1x(n-3) - b_2a_2x(n-4)$$
$$ = b_0net(n)+b_1net(n-1)+b_2net(n-2) - a_1\left(b_0x(n-1) + b_1x(n-2) + b_2x(n-3)\right) - a_2\left(b_0x(n-2) + b_1x(n-3) + b_2x(n-4)\right)$$
From here, it can be observed the parts multiplied with $a_1$ and $a_2$ are actually equal to a shifted version of the original equation of $\tilde{y}(n)$! by replacing them with the these shifted outputs, your equation in question will show up:
$$\tilde{y}(n) = b_0net(n)+b_1net(n-1)+b_2net(n-2) - a_1\tilde{y}(n-1) - a_2\tilde{y}(n-2)$$

Comment: An easier way of showing this I think would be by using $z$ such that $x(n+k)=z^k\,x(n)$. Such that $x(n)\,(1+a_1\,z^{-1}+a_2\,z^{-2})=net(n)$ and $\tilde{y}(n)=x(n)\,(b_0+b_1\,z^{-1}+b_2\,z^{-2})$, then solve the first equation for $x(n)$ and substitute that into the second equation.